# How/where can I insert \date{\today} in my amsbook driver file?

Tags: amsbook, date

I do understand that the amsbook style does not support including a \date. However, I really need this to keep track of progressive versions of my monograph ms. I see that the amsbook chapter-template.tex driver file actually includes \date [sic!] just before the \maketitle, but \date does not actually print any date (\today or any other date) on the .pdf that compiles.

Comment: One point of `\date{somedate}` is to get that date into the title/front page.  Since that doesn't make sense for a book (and you're not wanting it anyway), can't you just have "compiled on \today" somewhere in the frontmatter before you get to the meet of the book?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: One possibility is to include an extra paragraph at the end of the abstract with this information.  It won't be on the title page, but it should be on the next page.

Comment: You both gave me the idea of just adding \\ \today within the argument of \author{}. Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much. Solved!

Answer (score 1):

There are two commands that you're asking about: `\today` will turn into some representation of the date.  `\date{argument}` will (depending on the documentclass) turn into something like "Date: argument".

If `amsbook` isn't providing `\date`, then you can still use `\today` in other locations.  For example, the frontmatter (before you get into the actual contents) could contain: `Version: \today` to become the output "Version April 11, 2020".